# Pattern Match Text And Extract Data in C++

Tags: c++, find, pattern-matching

I am trying to figure out how I would go about extracting text from a text file if it matches the same pattern as a second text file and putting the extracted values into another text file.
I have never done anything like this before so I don't even know where to start.

So as an example, In file 1 we might have something like this:

```
else
        {
            if (func_133212(13))
            {
                if (unk_0x44334545("test"))
                {
                    if (!0x22224334545("test"))
                    {
                        0x44444237945("test", true);
                    }
                }
                if (Global_2398334.f_502.f_11 >= 2)
                {
                    if (unk_0x44334545("test2"))
                    {
                        if (!0x22224334545("test2"))
                        {
                            0x44444237945("test2", true);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

And then in file 2 we have something like:

```
else
        {
            if (func_12312(13))
            {
                if (unk_0x433877545("test"))
                {
                    if (!unk_0x3434344("test"))
                    {
                        unk_0x42224442111("test", true);
                    }
                }
                if (Global_23445454.f_502.f_11 >= 2)
                {
                    if (unk_0x433877545("test2"))
                    {
                        if (!unk_0x3434344("test2"))
                        {
                            unk_0x42224442111("test2", true);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

The program would recognize they have the same pattern and extract the unk_ 's into a list with the unk_ from file 1 on the left and the unk_ from file 2 on the right like so:

unk_0x44334545, unk_0x433877545

etc. etc.

I know this is quite complicated so any help is really really appreciated, Let me know if you need more info or anything like that. Just trying to get an idea of how to go about doing this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "same pattern". Does whitespace matter, for example? And do you want to do this for any language or just for one?

One quick algorithm for one specific language could be:

1. Load each file in memory as a single string.
2. Tokenize these strings on the special separator characters (such as: {}()>=.;), but keep those tokens in your sequences. This transforms your input strings into lists of tokens.
3. Trim all tokens of whitespace. This allows you to ignore whitespace differences. For example, your goal is to get a sequence like this from the first file: `else, {, if, (, func_133212, (, 13, ), ...`
4. Now you can compare the two lists linearly and you can output the pairs that don't match. You can also add some logic that says that for outputting a pair, you need a match of both the element before and after - thus, two successive mismatches would stop your comparison.

Something like this would work for the example you showed and could also be adjusted to work for more complicated examples. Also, if you need to handle larger files, you could stream in their contents and compare them gradually, but that would require more coding.

Comment: Whitespace does not matter. As I said before I really have no idea how to do any of this, in saying that could you give a small example to give me a starting point if you have time? I would really appreciate it. Thank you for your contribution already though, it has given me a lot more understanding of what I need to do.

Comment: All of these steps are about straightforward file reading and string processing. You can find sample code for such operations online or if you have a very specific aspect that you find tricky, then you can ask for an answer here, in a different question.